# How to change this code to a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

So, I wrote the following code to countdown from a number that a user enters down to 0. I need help on how I would take this code and change it to a recursive function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

  int count;
  printf ("Please enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d", &count);

  while (count > -1)
  {
    if (count != 0)
    {
       printf ("%d \n", count);
    }
    else
    {
       printf ("%d\nBlast Off!", count);
    } 

    count--;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/KrVu0D)

Answer (score 3):

Just get the base case and then call it again with the modified parameter. That will do the trick

```
void fun(int c){
  if( c == 0){
     printf ("%d\nBlast Off!", c);
      return;
  }
  printf ("%d \n", c);
  fun(c-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that takes an int.

```
Test if given int is 0, 
  if so print "Blast off".
  if not print the int and call the same function with int-1

call function with your user input integer.
```

done

Answer (score 1):

To write a recursive function you need a base case where the function terminates.

```
void blastOff(int time)
{
    if(time == 0) //Base Case
    {
     printf ("%d\nBlast Off!", count)
     return;
    }
    else
    {
      printf ("%d \n", count);
      blastOff(time -1);          
    }

}
```

Comment: this would print out `0` and `Blast off` for `0`

Comment: You're right fixed it.

Comment: `count` --> `time`, (but Since library function names are reserved, other names should be used)

Answer (score 0):

All code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int regressive(int i){
  if(i == 0){
     printf ("%d\nBlast Off!", i);
     return i;
  }
  else{
     printf ("%d \n", i);
     return regressive(i-1);
  }   
}

int main (){
  int count;
  printf ("Please enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d", &count);
  regressive(count);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

As it is supported that the function does something only when its parameter has a negative value then it is reasonable to declare the parameter as having the type `unsigned int`.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_down( unsigned int n )
{

    printf( "%u\n", n );

    n == 0 ? ( void )puts( "Blast Off!" ) : count_down( n - 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf ( "Please enter a number (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf ( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        count_down( n );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter a number (0 - exit): 10

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
Blast Off!

Please enter a number (0 - exit): 5

5
4
3
2
1
0
Blast Off!

Please enter a number (0 - exit): 0
```

If you want else that the demonstrative program ould make output for the value 0 then just substitute the while loop for a do-while loop. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_down( unsigned int n )
{

    printf( "%u\n", n );

    n == 0 ? ( void )puts( "Blast Off!" ) : count_down( n - 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n = 0;

    do
    {
        printf ( "Please enter a number (0 - exit): " );

        n = 0;

        if ( scanf ( "%u", &n ) != 1 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        count_down( n );

        putchar( '\n' );
    } while ( n );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter a number (0 - exit): 5

5
4
3
2
1
0
Blast Off!

Please enter a number (0 - exit): 0

0
Blast Off!
```

Comment: This is different from the OP code when 0 or a negative number is entered. Note that `%u` accepts negative numbers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I wrote that there is no sense to consider negative numbers because the function does nothing for such numbers. As for 0 then there behavior is the same.

Comment: The result when 0 is input is `0\n
Blast Off!`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY And what is the difference?

Comment: For your code, simply quit the application. Nothing is displayed. I do not want to say too ridiculous things.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It has nothing common with the function. You can call the function with the value o if you like.

Comment: As already pointed out, please note that even if you enter -1, it will be called.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY As I already pointed out the function does not make sense for negative arguments because it does nothing.

Comment: So why not check it? (I think this is a fatal shortcoming.)
The meaning changed to `unsigned` is not that much profitable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY O'l you can write yourself silly functions that deal with only non-negative numbers but always check whether a number is negative. Pay attention to that there are unsigned integer types in C.

Comment: What I am talking about is your code `%u` accepted a negative number
It means to do a terrible run.  (I already presented the code.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What you are speaking about is your own bad style of programming and nothing more. Take into account that for example standard string functions can accept negative values for the parameter of the type size_t and what?  Does it mean that you always ignore the requirements and try to pass a negative number?

Comment: What I am talking about is not such a thing. (My first comment is all.) I think that further discussion is meaningless and I will quit.